# Dynamically add data to ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I've a listview which already contain a list of data.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I click one of the ListItem, I want to add another bunch of dataset just below the clicked item.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        /* 
         * 
         * want to add another bunch of data just below postion 0!!!
         * 
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: what adapter are you using?

Comment: check @sapan answer then. You can also directly reference the adapter, so you don't have to do those cast

Comment: you want to add data like sub children for the selected item  or just as siblings on the same level if as siblings then check @sapan answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29) the data in the adapter that you use with list view and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to update the list view. You should use an ArrayAdapter (or its subclass) to be able to dynamically add objects to the list view.

```
((ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).insert(object, index);
((ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: check the insert (T object, int index) ref http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html, is that normal you try to insert an array of string?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[Another tutorial](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.be/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @jafar.
though what I want is a little bit different from ExpandableListView.